# Continuous function $f$ with $f^{-1}(\text{compact set}) = \text{non-compact set}$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. I know that

$$f(\text{compact}) = \text{compact}.$$

However, can you give me an **example of a compact set** such that

$$f^{-1}(\text{compact}) = \text{non-compact} ~?$$

Comment: Any constant function works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example: consider the constant function, $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, so $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathbb{R}$ correct?

Comment: @SimonMueller indeed.  I think you'll agree that $\{0\}$ is compact but $\Bbb R$ is not.