# Continuous function $f$ with $f^{-1}(\text{connected set}) = \text{non-connected set}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Can you give me an **example of a connected set** such that

$$f^{-1}(\text{connected}) = \text{non-connected} ~?$$

How should a *continuous* function split a set into to separate parts... an example would help me to understand it better.

This question is similar to the question I just asked but now with connected sets [Continuous function $f$ with $f^{-1}(\text{compact set}) = \text{non-compact set}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599717/continuous-function-f-with-f-1-textcompact-set-textnon-compact-set)

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^2$ and $\text{connected}=\{1\}$. Then $f^{-1}(\text{connected})=\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: You have posted similar (though not same) question a few minutes ago. Is there an assignment with tight deadline?

Comment: @HanulJeon I referred to my past question above. No, however I am currently learning for an exam that involves properties of sets and I'm trying to get a feeling for them.

Comment: Sorry for my impolite word. I hope you get nice grade.

Comment: Note that the continuous function does **not** split a connected set. In fact, it may 'join' a disconnected set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=\sin(x)$

$f^{-1}(0)=\{k\pi :k\in\Bbb Z\}$

$0$ is connected but $\{k\pi :k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is not

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x) = |x|$, then $f^{-1}([1,2]) = [-2,-1] \cup [1,2]$.